# Explicitly Set up multiple properties of specimen using AutoFixture customizations

Tags: c#, xunit, autofixture

I want to leverage xUnit theories together with AutoFixture to generate anonymous objects but with some explicit properties.

That's what i have now:

System under test

```
public class Task
{
    public TaskState TaskState { get; set;}
    public int Progress { get; set; }
}
```

Generic customization

```
public class PropertyCustomization<T> : ICustomization
{
    private readonly string propertyName;

    private readonly object value;

    public PropertyCustomization(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<T>(cmp => cmp.Do(obj => obj.SetProperty(this.propertyName, this.value)));
    }
}
```

..

```
public static void SetProperty(this object instance, string propertyName, object value)
{
    var propertyInfo = instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, value);
}
```

And attribute to use it

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public sealed class AutoTaskAttribute : CustomizeAttribute
{
    private readonly int progress;

    private readonly TaskState taskState;

    public AutoTaskAttribute(TaskState taskState, int progress = -1)
    {
        this.taskState = taskState;
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    public override ICustomization GetCustomization(ParameterInfo parameter)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parameter");
        }

        var result = new List<ICustomization> { new PropertyCustomization<Task>("TaskState", this.taskState) };

        if (this.progress > -1)
        {
            result.Add(new PropertyCustomization<Task>("Progress", this.progress));
        }

        return new CompositeCustomization(result);
    }
}
```

So, if I use it to specify only state like there, it works well and builds anonymous task

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void TestSomething([AutoTask(TaskState.InProgress)]Task task)
{...}
```

But if i want to setup both state and progress, it set up only second property for some reason, although both 'Do' delegates are called, but in the second call it receives task with default state again.

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void TestSomething([AutoTask(TaskState.InProgress, 50)]Task task)
{...}
```

I suspect that CompositeCustomization with multiple 'Do'-based customizations is the reason but don't get why.

Comment: Can you include the source code for `TaskState` and `SetProperty` as well?

Comment: How is the `TestSomething` method decorated?

Comment: I updated initial post. SetProperty just uses reflection to simply set the property of object, AutoMoqData attribute applies default AutoMoqCustomization

Comment: You're customizing `Task` twice, but one overrides the other.

Comment: it there any simple way  to "combine" 'Do' customizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because each next Type customization via Customize completely overrides previous one (Thanks to Mark for explanation).

So i changed customization to configure type rather than its property:

```
public class TypeCustomization<T> : ICustomization
{
    private List<Action<T>> actions;

    public TypeCustomization()
    {
        this.actions = new List<Action<T>>();
    }

    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customize<T>(
            cmp =>
                {
                    return this.actions.Aggregate<Action<T>, IPostprocessComposer<T>>(cmp, (current, next) => current.Do(next));
                });
    }

    public TypeCustomization<T> With(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        this.actions.Add(obj => obj.SetProperty(propertyName, value));
        return this;
    }
}
```

And it can be used in attribute definition like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public sealed class AutoTaskAttribute : CustomizeAttribute
{
    private readonly int progress;

    private readonly TaskState taskState;

    public AutoTaskAttribute(TaskState taskState, int progress = -1)
    {
        this.taskState = taskState;
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    public override ICustomization GetCustomization(ParameterInfo parameter)
    {
        var customization = new TypeCustomization<Task>().With("TaskState", this.taskState);

        if (this.progress > -1)
        {
            customization.With("Progress", this.progress);
        }

        return customization;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just do the following?

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void TestSomething(Task task)
{
    task.TaskState = TaskState.InProgress;

    // The rest of the test...
}
```

or this?

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void TestSomething(Task task)
{
    task.TaskState = TaskState.InProgress;
    task.Progress = 50;

    // The rest of the test...
}
```

This is much simpler, and type-safe too...

Comment: The main idea is to completely (more or less) move arrange statements in method parameters. Also i believe that generally [Task(InProgress)] task is more readable/smart that splitting declaration and assignments. Of course, if one have more than 2-3 parameters to set up, it's worth using this approach:)

Comment: ...your programming language of choice is *very good* at assigning values to properties. Why make this harder than it has to be?

Comment: To make tests smaller. Sure, if test is simple enough and requires only one task to assign these 2 properties, i'll do this explicitly. But imagine if you need to test task in appropriate state with 4-5 operations with different states and progress. Of course, you can do this explicitly in arrange phase but i believe that doing this via attributes may really simplify further test reading and understanding. After all, C# syntax is good enough to be used without xUnit attributes at all , just with explicit fixture instance. but i'd like to try this way

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot for your amazing AutoFixture.

Comment: @RR-Fireball ... but what *value* does it provide? If you need to call out explicit values in an attribute, you've saved neither typing nor cognitive overhead, but you *will* have lost type safety. You can still use `[AutoData]` to supply an initial value with all other properties filled, but if you have property values that are important for a test case, you'll need to state those values *somewhere*.

Comment: What's wrong with type safety there? Do you mean SetProperty reflection method? I just provided it there to simplify code in question, it can easily be replaced with type-safe impl. Talking about _value_: no more than just wish to provide all information about test object _in one place_, so if i read test, i immediately see that input task is the task with 50 progress and it's running now. To be honest, i'm not sure it's the best way to achieve this, but i want to try this way and look if this works.

Comment: You can only use constant values in attributes, so if you take this route, TDD will make force you towards *primitive obsession*. You wouldn't even be able to supply a `decimal`. If you want readable tests, you may consider [this heuristic approach](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/06/24/a-heuristic-for-formatting-code-according-to-the-aaa-pattern).

Comment: Sure, it won't work with non-constant data or non-primitive types, in this case other "readability" technique should be used. But in case when it's applicable, why not?:)

Comment: Because now you'd have two different ways of doing the same thing... In any case, I don't buy the argument that putting those constants in attributes make the tests more readable. The more *familiar* the code is, the more readable it tends to be. I have no problem with introducing unfamiliar constructs if the benefit from doing so makes it worthwhile. However, I have a hard time seeing the benefit here. A familiar C# construct is to use an assignment statement, so I would argue from a basic cognition argument that using that would make the tests more readable.

Comment: Well, it's definitely a matter of taste than. After all, AutoFixture itself is _a new way of doing the same thing_, and one can say that there is _more_ familiar construct (called object constructor) to do this:)